# NSNumberFormatter thousand seperator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter

I want to create thousand seperator. It works when I am typing numbers to textfield. Yet, I does not work when I delete an number from textfield.

Screenshot when I typed:

[image: testasdsadasdas].

Screenshot when I delete an number from text field:

[image]

But I want to have number like : 121.132 , could you help me to resolve that problem?

Code:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] ;
[formatter setGroupingSeparator:@"."];
[formatter setGroupingSize:2];
[formatter setUsesGroupingSeparator:YES];
[formatter setSecondaryGroupingSize:3];

NSString *num = textField.text ;
if(![num isEqualToString:@""]){
    num= [num stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@""];
    NSString *str = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[num doubleValue]]];
    textField.text=str;
 }
```

Comment: Where is this code placed? And why do you delete the period your own?

Comment: It is inside of shouldChangeCharactersInRange, users want to change it to write proper text, that's why, it should works while users are deleting texts

Comment: You're talking about `-textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`? Is your code executed on deleting?

Comment: Yes , it deletes but it puts dots to wrong place

Comment: ? Please log `textField.text` before you set it and `str`.

Comment: trace every char using `textField's` delegate method `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` then format.

Answer (score 0):

**Try any of these solutions:-**

**Solution 1**

```
 - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSNumberFormatter *nf = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] ;
    [nf setGroupingSize:3];
    [nf setCurrencyGroupingSeparator:@"."];
    [nf setUsesGroupingSeparator:YES];
    // you should create a string from number
    NSNumber *n = [NSNumber numberWithLong: 100000000];
    NSString *str = [nf stringFromNumber: n];
    textField.text = str;
    NSLog(@"My number: %@", str);
    return true;
}
```

**Solution 2**

```
    - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
    {
           NSString *strTest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@",textField.text,string];
            NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] ;
            [formatter setGroupingSeparator:@"."];
            [formatter setGroupingSize:2];
            [formatter setUsesGroupingSeparator:YES];
            [formatter setSecondaryGroupingSize:3];
            NSString *num = strTest ;
            if(![num isEqualToString:@""])
            {
                num= [num stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@""];
                NSString *str = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[num doubleValue]]];

                _textField.text=str;

            }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: It is same, it works while I am typing , but it does not work while I am deleting.

Comment: Inside of -textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString: